# Resetting SharpDX device after ctrl + alt + del

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, directx, sharpdx

I'm using SharpDX for developing a 3D modeling software where the elements are drawn with Vertex- and IndexBuffers. I'm a beginner in 3D graphics and DirectX, the code is not written by me and I'm trying to adapt it.
But here is the problem: Alt tabbing when debugging works fine but when locking and unlocking the computer or pressing ctrl + alt + del the state of the SharpDX.Direct3D9.Device I'm using changes to "DeviceNotReset". I am now trying to recover the device so rendering could continue.

Creating device:

```
public ModelerControl(MainViewPresenter parent)
    {
        PresentParameters par = new PresentParameters();
        par.Windowed = true;
        par.SwapEffect = SharpDX.Direct3D9.SwapEffect.Discard;
        par.PresentationInterval = PresentInterval.One;
        par.AutoDepthStencilFormat = SharpDX.Direct3D9.Format.D16;
        par.EnableAutoDepthStencil = true;
        par.BackBufferFormat = SharpDX.Direct3D9.Format.X8R8G8B8;
        par.BackBufferHeight = this.ClientSize.Height;
        par.BackBufferWidth = this.ClientSize.Width;

        if (device == null)
        {
            device = new SharpDX.Direct3D9.Device(new Direct3D(), 0, DeviceType.Hardware, this.Handle, CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing, par);

            SC = device.GetSwapChain(0);
        }
        else
        {
            SC = new SharpDX.Direct3D9.SwapChain(device, pp);
        }

        this.parentPresenter = parent;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Rendering and trying to reset the device:

```
public void Render()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            ModelerProperties properties = ProjectModel.Instance.Project.ModelerPropertyList;
            if (properties == null)
                return;
            if (!properties.IsPropertySenderInited)
            {
                properties.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(ModelerControl_PropertyChanged);
                properties.IsPropertySenderInited = true;
            }

            int index = 0;

            if (device == null)
                return;
            if (clock == null)
                return;
            if (SC.IsDisposed)
                return;
            if (this.IsDisposed)
                return;

            SharpDX.Result result = device.TestCooperativeLevel();

            if(result == ResultCode.DeviceNotReset)
            {
                PresentParameters pp = new PresentParameters();
                pp.Windowed = true;
                pp.SwapEffect = SharpDX.Direct3D9.SwapEffect.Discard;
                pp.PresentationInterval = PresentInterval.One;
                pp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = SharpDX.Direct3D9.Format.D16;
                pp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = true;
                pp.BackBufferFormat = SharpDX.Direct3D9.Format.X8R8G8B8;
                pp.BackBufferHeight = this.ClientSize.Height;
                pp.BackBufferWidth = this.ClientSize.Width;

                try
                {
                    device.Reset(pp);
                }
                catch { }
            }

            SharpDX.Direct3D9.Surface bb = SC.GetBackBuffer(0);
            device.SetRenderTarget(0, bb);

            device.Clear(ClearFlags.Target | ClearFlags.ZBuffer, properties.GetBackGroundColor(), 1.0f, 0);
            device.BeginScene();

            //Defining matrices

            device.SetTransform(TransformState.World, ref mScale);
            device.SetTransform(TransformState.View, ref mView);
            device.SetTransform(TransformState.Projection, ref mProj);

            device.SetRenderState(RenderState.PointSpriteEnable, true);
            device.SetRenderState(RenderState.PointScaleA, 0f);
            device.SetRenderState(RenderState.PointScaleB, 0f);
            device.SetRenderState(RenderState.PointScaleC, 100f);
            device.SetRenderState(RenderState.Lighting, true);
            device.SetRenderState(RenderState.Ambient, System.Drawing.Color.White.ToArgb());
            device.SetRenderState(RenderState.ZEnable, ZBufferType.UseZBuffer);
            device.SetRenderState(RenderState.NormalizeNormals, true);
            device.SetRenderState(RenderState.CullMode, Cull.Counterclockwise);

            device.SetRenderState(RenderState.AlphaBlendEnable, true);
            device.SetRenderState(RenderState.BlendOperation, BlendOperation.Add);
            device.SetRenderState(RenderState.SourceBlend, Blend.SourceAlpha);
            device.SetRenderState(RenderState.DestinationBlend, Blend.InverseSourceAlpha);

            //Drawing elements

            device.EndScene();

            try
            {
                 SC.Present(Present.None, new SharpDX.Rectangle(), new SharpDX.Rectangle(), this.Handle);
            }
            catch { }

            bb.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

When adding a breakpoint at device resetting, pressing ctrl + alt + delete and continuing, an SharpDXException is catched with the message `HRESULT: [0x8876086C], Module: [SharpDX.Direct3D9], ApiCode: [D3DERR_INVALIDCALL/InvalidCall], Message: Unknown`

Doing the same thing but at the line `SC.Present(Present.None, new SharpDX.Rectangle(), new SharpDX.Rectangle(), this.Handle);`, a SharpDXException gets thrown with the following message `HRESULT: [0x88760868], Module: [SharpDX.Direct3D9], ApiCode: [D3DERR_DEVICELOST/DeviceLost], Message: Unknown`

I think I am supposed to release the resources and then reset the device but the reset method is throwing the exception. Or should the device be recreated when the exception at `SC.Present()` says that the device is lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't get the resetting of the device to work, instead I created a new `SharpDX.Device` with the same  `PresentParameters` as above. Then I just reinitialized the graphics and that seems to work fine. May not be the most efficient way but in this case it works.